# Python Pandas: to_panel() from dataframe returns weird numbers for binary variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel, fixed

I have a *dataset* that I read in like so:

```
pm10 = pds.read_csv('pm10.csv', index_col = [0,1], parse_dates=True)
panel_exog = pm10.to_panel()['pass_ind']
```

but when I do the conversion, the returned panel has large integer numbers where there are supposed to be zeros (or 1s). I had to add ".0" to all rows of that binary variable to make it work the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

I reported a bug here. I've seen one other bug report on `to_panel`, some additional info posted on GitHub (e.g. link to data file) would be useful:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1582

Answer (score 0):

`time_effects` is a valid parameter only for a `panel OLS`, not for a `simple OLS`.
From pandas docs:

```
def ols(**kwargs):
"""Returns the appropriate OLS object depending on whether you need
simple or panel OLS, and a full-sample or rolling/expanding OLS.

Will be a normal linear regression or a (pooled) panel regression depending
on the type of the inputs:

y : Series, x : DataFrame -> OLS
y : Series, x : dict of DataFrame -> OLS
y : DataFrame, x : DataFrame -> PanelOLS
y : DataFrame, x : dict of DataFrame/Panel -> PanelOLS
y : Series with MultiIndex, x : Panel/DataFrame + MultiIndex -> PanelOLS
```

Can you post the CSV file you are using, to find out what OLS you are trying to do?

EDIT: from the CSV you posted it's clear that you are passing to `pandas.ols` two `Series` objects. From the above docstring, to do a `PanelOLS` you need to pass two `DataFrames` instead.

Comment: Was the original question edited to not be about panel regression anymore?

Comment: Yes, but my "Edit" was before the "Edit" in the question. In fact, I think the original question should be closed as this is a complete new one.